# CoffeeScript always returns in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to write some CoffeScript function which checks all checkboxes in a table upon checking the checkbox in the th.

My function in CoffeeScript looks like this:

```
$("table.tableview th input:checkbox").live 'click', -> 
  checkedStatus = this.checked
  $("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each ->
      this.checked = checkedStatus
```

It works great for checking all the boxes. However when unchecking it doesn't work. The compiled JS looks like this:

```
$("table.tableview th input:checkbox").live('click', function() {
  var checkedStatus;
  checkedStatus = this.checked;
  return $("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each(function() {
    return this.checked = checkedStatus;
  });
});
```

It doesn't work because after the first one is set to false the return of the function will be false. I however have no clue how to suppress this default return behavior of coffee script. Please help.

When I add a "true" as per Flambino's suggestion I get the following JS

```
$("table.tableview th input:checkbox").live('click', function() {
    var checkedStatus;
    checkedStatus = this.checked;
    $("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each(function() {
        return this.checked = checkedStatus;
    });
    return true;
});
```

The only way I can get the return statement inside the function is by putting it all the way like this:

```
$("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each ->
    this.checked = checkedStatus
true
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thx for the help so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a `true` as the last line of your function, and coffeescript will compile the JS to return that instead:

```
$("table.tableview th input:checkbox").live 'click', -> 
    checkedStatus = this.checked
    $("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each ->
        this.checked = checkedStatus
    true
```

In other words, CoffeeScript always returns the result of the last line (like Ruby does)

---

**Edit (after the question was updated):**

Again, you can't keep CoffeeScript from returning the value of the last line in a function - part of the point of CoffeeScript is that it does exactly that.

CoffeeScript has significant whitespace, so indentation is what says what belongs together - your example is is actually correct:

```
$("table.tableview th input:checkbox").live 'click', -> 
    checkedStatus = this.checked
    $("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each ->
        this.checked = checkedStatus
        true // cause this function (the each-iterator) to return true
    true // causes the click handler function to return true
```

There's no difference between this and just writing `return true` in a function like you would in javascript. You just use whitespace instead of `{}` to make code blocks.

Comment: Yep. Doesn't look like there's a way to supress coffeescripts return behavior.  https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1401

Comment: @Flambino I understood it that far. And my question basically was already answered by your first post ;) thx for that. I did however have the issue that if I used the indentation you prescribed I ended up with the return true statement on the wrong line. Turned out there was some tab vs spaces issue in my file which screwed up the "significant whitespace" scopes of CoffeeScript. Glad I figured that out. Thx again for the help

Comment: @Gidogeek: Ah, yeah, watch out for tabs vs. soft-tabs (spaces). Usually 1 real tab has the width of 2-4 spaces, but it still only counts as 1 whitespace character. If you have an option to "show invisibles" in your text editor, that's a great help, since it should make the tabs plainly visible.

Answer (score 20):

If you just use `return` (or, equivalently, `undefined`) as the last line of a function, the CoffeeScript compiler will give you JS with no `return` at all. So the most efficient way of writing your code would be

```
$("table.tableview th input:checkbox").live 'click', -> 
  checkedStatus = this.checked
  $("table.tableview tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each ->
    this.checked = checkedStatus
    return
  return
```

(You can safely do without the second `return`, of course. Only a return value of `false` has an effect in jQuery.)

There was also a proposed syntax (`-/>`) for defining a function with no return value; see [issue 899](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/899).