# from Javascript to CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

How to write this javascript code in coffeeScript?

```
$('#id_tab a').click(function (e) {
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
})
```

It works when i put it in my html.erb file

So I try this in the coffeeScript file:

```
$ ->
    $('#id_tab a').click (e) ->
        $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass 'active'
        $(this).parent('li').addClass 'active'
```

And it doesn't work.
Please help!

Comment: You've done it. That *is* how you write that code in CoffeeScript. Your problem is external to this code, possibly related to that actual inclusion of the file. Try adding an `alert("!!!")` to the top of the file and see if the file is even being included in your page.

Comment: The first line in the CoffeeScript "$ ->" is extra. You would only need that line if you had $(function() {...} in your original JS code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice site called [JS2Coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) which you can use to check your script. You'll see that your coffee script compiles to:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#id_tab a').click(function(e) {
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
    return $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Instead, try this:

```
$ ->
    $('#id_tab a').click (e) ->
        $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass 'active'
        $(this).parent('li').addClass 'active'
        true
    true
```

You can view this [StackOveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042140/coffeescript-always-returns-in-anonymous-function) answer for more information, but Coffeescript always returns the last line.